# Why $\text{top}h$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

I am reading the book [Elements of representation theory of associative algebras](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC)

I have a question about from Line -9 to Line -6 of page 29, the proof of Theorem 5.8.

[image: Page 29]

How to show that $\text{top}h$  is an isomorphism and $\ker h \subseteq \ker t$? It seems that we can only conclude that $\text{top}h$ is surjective because $t'$ is surjective.

If $x\in P(M)$ such that $h(x)=0$, then $\text{top}h (t(x))=\text{top}h (x+\text{rad}P(M))=h(x)+\text{rad}M=\text{rad}M$. We only know that $h(x)\in \text{rad}M$ and we don't know that $x$ is in $\text{rad}P(M)$ or not. We know that $h(\text{rad}P(M)) \subseteq \text{rad}M$. Can we conclude that $\text{rad}P(M) \subseteq h^{-1}(\text{rad}M)$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would guess that the idea is that if a proper submodule $N$ of $top(P(M))$ would cover $top(M)$, then the preimage of $N$ in $P(M)$ would already map surjectively onto $M$. Hard to tell exactly, as I have no idea what has been covered up to that point (and I can't read google books).